# Qt, How to pause QThread immediately

Tags: qt, qthread

I have an `QThread` which listen server. I want to pause work of `QThread` immediately. Not waiting at all, but almost like terminating, it must be immediate.

Comment: Can you provide some code. It's not clear now what you mean. As you see, msleep method pause work of thread immediately. Is it what you want?

Comment: _"it must cut like knife"_ O_o

Comment: run function of QThread emit a signal. I want to terminate stuff alrealdy works emitted by signal.

Comment: Are you using Qt networking classes, or some other (blocking) listen call? Anyway, this question needs the relevant code!

Answer (score 22):

A code running in any given thread cannot be stopped at an arbitrary point without corrupting the state of the shared data structures in your code and/or the C/C++ runtime or any other libraries that are used.

The code can only stop at well-defined points.

If your thread runs an event loop (i.e. usually if you don't derive from `QThread` or don't override its `run`), then `QThread::quit()` will stop the thread once it returns control to the event loop, where it's safe to do so.

If your thread reimplements run and executes a loop there, it should return when interruption is requested:

```
void MyThread::run() {
  while (! isInterruptionRequested()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Such a thread is stoppable by `QThread::requestInterruption()`.

For reference, here are various methods of `QThread` that are sometimes confused:

- `wait()` blocks the calling thread until the called thread finishes. Of course, calling it from within the thread itself is instant deadlock: a thread can't finish if it waits for something that's never going to happen.
- `quit()` quits the thread's event loop at the earliest opportunity, and causes `QThread::run()` to return. It does nothing if you're reimplemented `run()` and don't spin an event loop.
- `requestTermination()` sets a flag that a custom loop in `YourThread::run()` can check via `isTerminationRequested()`.
- `terminate()` stops the thread **now**. This generally corrupts the state of your application, so you must `abort()` sometime soon or face the consequences. This method is best forgotten about. It essentially means "crash this process soon and corrupt some disk data if you get a chance".